# Multiple files - awk command filter

Tags: awk

I use a script say; filter1.sh which contains awk command;

```
bzip2 -dc File_1.tsv.bz2 | awk -F '\t' 'BEGIN {OFS=FS} { if (($7) > 50)  print $0 }'  > File_1.tsv

bzip2 -dc File_2.tsv.bz2 | awk -F '\t' 'BEGIN {OFS=FS} { if (($7) > 50)  print $0 }'  > File_2.tsv
```

to open bz2 file and filter the values in column 7 that are greater than 50 and and write the output to a new tsv file.

I have multiple files (around 200 which are located in different directories) for which I have to perform this filtering step (note exactly the same but similar).

My question here is how do I pass multiple files for this purpose, Is it possible to pass the files through separate INFILE (like in python).

Something like;

```
./filter1.sh pathtofiles.in
```

in command line. Where pathtofiles.in contains location of files.

```
/home/users/gray_wolf/unix/File_1.tsv.bz2
/home/users/gray_wolf/unix/File_2.tsv.bz2
.
.
.
.
.
```

and so on.

thanks in advance. ~M

Comment: Re awk-script `awk -F'\t' '$7>50' > File_1.tsv` is enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
while read f
do
    bzip2 -dc "$f" | 
    awk -F '\t' 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} $7 > 50' > "$(basename "$f" .bz2)"
done < list-of-file.txt
```

1. awk will write result from File_1.tsv.bz2 to File_1.tsv, and so one with File_2, ... File_960.
2. you give the list of file in `list-of-file.txt`
3. `> $(basename $f .bz2)` will create result in local dir

Answer (score 3):

You could get them all in a single output stream like:

```
bzip2 -dc ./File_*.bz2 | filter
```

To write them out to separate files on output you'd need to delimit the stream in some way. This would be the ideal solution if you could arrange it - and with more information you could get help in doing so.

Else you can call up your filters individually once per input file:

```sh
for j in ./File_*.bz2
do    [ -f "$j" ] &&
      bzip2 -dc "$j" |
      awk ... >"${j%.*}"
done
```

This is not ideal in that you have to call up a new instance of your pipeline per file, but may be a practical solution for you.

To source such a `for` loop in another script file and then to pass it the arguments you want it to work with you could do:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
for j do
      case $j in
      (*.bz2) [ -f "$j" ] &&
              bzip2 -dc --  "$j" |
              awk ...   >"${j.*}"
      esac
done
```

...which is only slightly more complicated so that it might ensure all of its arguments are definitely named with a `*.bz2` extension to avoid any nastiness as might surround passing in an argument with no extension., If written to an executable file named *`./script`* on a system with a POSIX `/bin/sh`, it could be called like...

```sh
./script ./File_*.bz2
```

Answer (score 0):

In bash, you can try this:

```
for f in `cat $1`
do
  bzip ...
done
```

This may not work in all shells, and there are undoubtedly other ways to accomplish this. `$1` means "the first parameter passed to the script".

Comment: Watch out for any files with spaces in the names as `f` will get each part split on `IFS` separately.  This is basically the [don't parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) problem

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r j
do 
    [ -f "$j" ] && 
    bzip2 -dc "$j" |
    sed -r '/^([^\t]+\t){6}0*([1-9][0-9]{2,}|[6-9][0-9]|5[1-9])/! d' > "${j%.*}"
done <"$1"
```